# Problemas com Sessões PHP e Requisições Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, htaccess, session

Essa é pra quem é fera, haha.

Eu tenho um site hospedado (por questão de privacidade, não divulgarei o link) que o segmento é de ***equipamentos de proteção individual***. Tem os produtos para adicionar no carrinho.

**Situação problemática 1:** O site utiliza `HTTP`;
**Situação problemática 2:** Estou tentando fazer uma requisição de um site que usa `HTTP` (do cliente) para um site que usa `HTTPS` (Um site sob meus cuidados, vamos chama-lo de **Site Geral**);

Tendo lido essas duas **problemáticas**, o site do cliente precisa acessar o Site Geral porque eu utilizo um arquivo `Funcoes.php` nele que possui funções de **adicionar** e **remover** itens do carrinho. 
Porém (Claro que tem 'porém'), eu precisei fazer todo aquele processo de adicionar os cabeçalhos de Controle de Acesso de Permissão de Origem para permitir as funcionalidades.

O que eu fiz já:

- Acrescentei os detalhes no meu arquivo `.htaccess` conforme abaixo:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
          Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
  </IfModule>
  ```
- Também acrescentei o `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` no `Funcoes.php` usando `PHP`

  ```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  ```

No final, o processo fica mais ou menos assim:

Quando eu adiciono o produto ao carrinho, um `script` javascript pega os dados e envia para o `Funcoes.php` via `Ajax`, conforme abaixo:

```
function addItemOrcamento(thumbnail, nome, id, url, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var qtd = parseInt($("#orcamentoQtd").val(), 10);
    var data = {Acao: "addItemOrcamento", thumbnail: thumbnail, nome: nome, id: id, qtd: qtd};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://sitegeral.com.br/sistema/Funcoes.php',
        type: 'POST',        
        data: data,
        success: function(r){
            console.log(r);
            window.location = url;
        }
    })    
}
```

Então quando eu disparo o evento **"AddItemOrcamento"** ele redireciona para a página **orcamento.php** do site do cliente, conforme programado, mas ele não adiciona o item no carrinho e no `console` do Google Chrome ele mostra um erro muito rápido antes de redirecionar para a página **orcamento.php**. O erro é de index indefinido. Confira abaixo o erro:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: items in <b>/home/arkalis/web/siteaqui.com/public_html/sistema/Funcoes.php</b> on line <b>1664</b><br/>
```

E pra terminar com chave de ouro, vou inserir a função `PHP` que é responsável por pegar os dados da $_SESSION['items'] e trabalhar com elas.

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Vou colocar a função PHP seguida da inicialização da sessão usada no site do cliente.

**Funcoes.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['Acao']) && $_POST['Acao'] == "addItemOrcamento") {
    if (isset($_POST['thumbnail']) && isset($_POST['nome']) && isset($_POST['id']) && isset($_POST['qtd'])) {

        $peculiaridade = isset($_POST['peculiaridade']) ? $_POST['peculiaridade'] : false;

        $i = 0;
        $itemExiste = false;
        $items = $_SESSION['items'];

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($items); $i++) {
            $items[$i]["peculiaridade"] = isset($items[$i]["peculiaridade"]) ? $items[$i]["peculiaridade"] : false;
            if ($items[$i]["pro_id"] == $_POST['id'] && $items[$i]["peculiaridade"] == $peculiaridade) {
                $itemExiste = true;
                $items[$i]["qtd"] += $_POST['qtd'];
                $_SESSION['items'] = $items;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$itemExiste) {
            $item = Array("thumbnail" => $_POST['thumbnail'],
                "pro_nome" => $_POST['nome'],
                "pro_id" => $_POST['id'],
                "qtd" => $_POST['qtd'],
                "peculiaridade" => $peculiaridade
            );
            $_SESSION['items'][] = $item;
            sort($_SESSION['items']);
            echo "ok";
        } else {
            echo "item somado";
        }
    } else {
        die("Erro ao adicionar item para orçamento!");
    }
}
```

*Esse arquivo está presente no meu site, ok?*

**$_SESSION['items']**

```
if (!$_SESSION) {
    session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
    $_SESSION['items'] = array();
}
```

*site do cliente*

**NOTA IMPORTANTE:** Se eu colocar tudo em `HTTP` (isso é, meu site né) ele funciona perfeitamente, essa não é a questão ok? E também colocar tudo em `HTTPS`, isso não é uma escolha minha, eu não decido essa parte, então não poderei fazer. A situação é `HTTP` to `HTTPS`.

Terminei. 
Eu realmente sinto muito por essa pergunta ter ficado grande, as vezes o pessoal não gosta e nem responde a pergunta. Mas se você pode me ajudar, por favor comente sua resposta. 
Agradeço aí a todos que sempre me ajudam nas minhas questões me fazendo assim ter um resultado melhor na comunidade Stackoverflow.

Necessitando de qualquer outra informação, estarei aqui para acrescentar/editar.

Comment: Como está configurado os cookies e segurança de sessão? É possível que esteja bloqueado para HTTP

Comment: Os comandos usados no `.htaccess` não cuidariam desse problema? Eu estava com esse problema de bloqueio de requisição http to https e inseri eles para desativar essas restrições, achei que isso funcionaria para outros tipos de chamadas.

Comment: Não, o que você colocou ali é apenas configuração de CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível realizar chamadas via HTTP em um site rodando em HTTPS pois o navegador bloqueia. Isso faz parte da política de segurança do HTTPS. Porém, existem algumas alternativas.

A primeira delas é desativar as restrições de origem cruzada (Cross Origin Restrictions) no navegador. No Chrome por exemplo, você pode inicializa-lo passando os parâmetros `--disable-web-security --user-data-dir=~/.chrome-disable-web-security`. Mas isso vai depender de uma configuração do lado do usuário, portanto só irá funcionar se você tiver acesso e controle ao ambiente dos usuários.

A segunda é utilizar o proxy reverso simples, que no caso receberia a sua requisição na aplicação rodando em HTTPS e faria a chamada via servidor para a aplicação rodando em HTTP.

Você pode utilizar ferramentas de proxy disponíveis como o [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/), ou fazer a chamada direto pelo PHP. Ex:

A aplicação 1 faz uma chamada para um arquivo PHP, e este arquivo faz uma chamada HTTP (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.request.php) para aplicação 2, que devolve o resultado para o arquivo PHP que devolve para a Aplicação 1.

Comment: Sério que não é possível? Eu fiz isso referente aos e-mails e deu certo, alias está dando, achei que isso valia para outras tipos de chamadas também.

Comment: Diego Marques, vou marcar a sua resposta como correta porque eu gostei da sua orientação sobre proxy reverso. Então depois irei simular uma situação igual a essa que passei pra testar essa sua dica que achei interessante. Vlw. Eu resolvi de um jeito meio que não queria, que é colocar as funções dentro da pasta do site do cliente, já que o site dele fica dentro do site que eu administro. kkkk mas vlw